# Null Pointer exception while initialize@ PostConstruct method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, postconstruct

I am getting **NullPointerException** while initializing `@PostConstruct` method

My **startup class** code:

```
@Component
public class Startup {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostConstruct
    private void createAdmin() {
        try {
            User user = userService.findByUsername("admin123");
            if (user == null) {
                user.setFirstName("administrator");
                user.setLastName("administrator");
                user.setGender("Male");
                user.setDob(Date.valueOf("2019-06-13"));
                user.setEmail("administrator@gmail.com");
                user.setAddress("administrator address");
                user.setUsername("admin123");
                user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("admin123"));
                user.setPhoneNumber("123456789");
                user.setIsActive(Status.getActiveUser());
                user.setRole(Role.getRoleAdmin());
                userService.saveUser(user);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Instead of `@Component` I have change to `@service` and `UserService` to `UserRepository` and this time I get different exception saying:

> Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread exception.

Where am I getting this wrong?

And here is exception log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mhs.goodsexchangehinge.init.Startup.createAdmin(Startup.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `user != null` instead of `user == null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `(user == null)` to `(user != null)`

Comment: It save me from getting null pointer exception but user details are not save.

Comment: @Mohammadhussain Then you should first create a user object before try to call setters on it.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel  but it should after try not before. A silly mistake was done.

Comment: I was missing this one:  **@PostConstruct**
    **private void createAdmin() {**
       ** try {**
            **User u = userService.findByUsername("admin123");**
            **if (u == null) { User user =new User();}**'